# TimeStamp Standard PHP

Tags: php

I am working on creating a log file where log details including timestamp should be written to the log file. But is there any standard timestamp function which I can use in the php code which does not show any sort of errors like "You cannot rely on SYstem's timezone' etc
.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$stamp = time();
```

Comment: Proper date and time as in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MMam/pm? the `date` function will do the trick.

Comment: but date() requires atleast one parameter?

Comment: i used date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

Comment: Change the `GMT` part to the Country/City you're in, for example `Australia/Sydney`, there's also a [complete list of timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) on the PHP site.

Answer (score 1):

See [`date_default_timezone_set(..)`](https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to get rid of that error.

Otherwise use [`time()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and [`date(..)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).